# Auth0 : Disable social signup and move current records to DB user

Tags: reactjs, locking, auth0

I want to disable social connections on Auth0 and leave only database user records.

My question is how do I migrate or convert existing users who have signed up through Google and Facebook to a database user and conserve their user metadata?

Comment: You can provide more context / example of how your users are stored and what kind of migration are you expecting.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the social users to create database accounts, the two accounts can be merged using [account linking](https://auth0.com/docs/link-accounts). Specifically, [there's a rule](https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/src/rules/link-users-by-email-with-metadata.js) that merges the user's metadata during linking.

Note that this won't prevent new users from signing up with a social account. For that, you can use a rule that [disables social signup](https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/src/rules/disable-social-signup.js).